# Resultset Closed

Tags: java, jdbc

This code give me that:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      

    String UI=null;

    String sql="select * from Outcome";
    try {
        sta=con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        rs=sta.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {

        while(rs.next()){
             UI=rs.getString("OutID");
            if(UI.equals(jTextField5.getText())){
                System.out.println("\n"+UI);
          UI=jTextField5.getText();
            String Des=jTextField6.getText();
            String Mo=jTextField7.getText();
            String Da=String.valueOf(jComboBox4.getSelectedItem())+"/"+String.valueOf(jComboBox5.getSelectedItem())+"/"+String.valueOf(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem());
           String Not=jTextField8.getText();

            String st = String.format("UPDATE Outcome SET OutID = '%s', Description = '%s', MoneyAmount = '%s', ODate = '%s', Notes = '%s'",UI,Des,Mo,Da,Not);
                  sta.executeUpdate(st);

          //  ps.setString(1, jTextField5.getText());
            //ps.setString(2,jTextField6.getText());
           // ps.setString(3,jTextField7.getText());
            //ps.setString(4,String.valueOf(jComboBox4.getSelectedItem()+"/"+String.valueOf(jComboBox5.getSelectedItem())+"/"+String.valueOf(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem())));

                sta.close();

                con.close();

            }


        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

**The Exception**:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ‏‏[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] ‏‏حالة رأس المؤشر غير صالحة
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
at comcentrt.Outcomes.jButton4ActionPerformed(Outcomes.java:861)
at comcentrt.Outcomes.access$3(Outcomes.java:846)
at comcentrt.Outcomes$5.actionPerformed(Outcomes.java:380)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you add some content what you are exactly trying to do?

Comment: I'm not intending to be offensive, but I *really* don't understand what that exception message is saying.

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of an operation in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block.

Comment: In addition to the comment by EJP, the fact that the statement and the resultset are not local variables, but instance fields is a big red flag (and the connection is a case of doubt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed the connection inside the while loop

```
con.close();
```

that is why you are getting exception.
Close that after the while loop

```
while(rs.next())
{
 // your code
}
con.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues, but lets start with what's probably causing you issues...

```
while(rs.next()){
    UI=rs.getString("OutID");
    if(UI.equals(jTextField5.getText())){
        System.out.println("\n"+UI);
        //...
        sta.executeUpdate(st);

        // This probably won't help...
        sta.close();
        // This will definitely not help...
        con.close();
    }

}
```

You are closing the underlying `Statement` which generated the `ResultSet`, but more importantly, you're closing the actually `Connection`, so the next time you call `rs.next`, the `ResultSet` will be reported as having been closed...

Also...

```
String st = String.format("UPDATE Outcome SET OutID = '%s', Description = '%s', MoneyAmount = '%s', ODate = '%s', Notes = '%s'",UI,Des,Mo,Da,Not);
sta.executeUpdate(st);
```

Will close the previous `ResultSet` (thanks to Mark Rotteveel).  You could use one of the `Result#updateXxx` methods, if it's supported by the JDBC driver and database, for example...

```
rs.update("OutID", UI);
```

Take a look at [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for more details...

If the JDBC driver/Database does not support this feature, you will need to create a new `Statement` to perform the operation.

Also, formatting a `String` this way and using it within a database statement this way...

```
String st = String.format("UPDATE Outcome SET OutID = '%s', Description = '%s', MoneyAmount = '%s', ODate = '%s', Notes = '%s'",UI,Des,Mo,Da,Not);
```

Is really, very dangerous.  It leaves you vulnerable to SQL inject attacks.  Instead, you should be using [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Also your resource management is less than optimal...

Have a look at this...

```
try {
    sta=con.createStatement();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
try {
    rs=sta.executeQuery(sql);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

What happens if `createStatement` throws an exception?  Now you have a potential `NullPointerException` when trying to call `executeQuery`

And look at this...

```
try {
    while(rs.next()){
        if(UI.equals(jTextField5.getText())){
            sta.close();
            con.close();
        }

    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

What happens if an exception is thrown before you call `close`?  It's very dangerous calling `close` within `try-catch` statements like this as it could mean that those resources are never closed.

Instead, you could Java 7's `try-with-resources`...

```
try (Statement sta = con.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(sql)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            UI = rs.getString("OutID");
            if (UI.equals(jTextField5.getText())) {
                System.out.println("\n" + UI);
                UI = jTextField5.getText();
                String Des = jTextField6.getText();
                String Mo = jTextField7.getText();
                String Da = String.valueOf(jComboBox4.getSelectedItem()) + "/" + String.valueOf(jComboBox5.getSelectedItem()) + "/" + String.valueOf(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem());
                String Not = jTextField8.getText();

                String st = String.format("UPDATE Outcome SET OutID = '%s', Description = '%s', MoneyAmount = '%s', ODate = '%s', Notes = '%s'", UI, Des, Mo, Da, Not);
                sta.executeUpdate(st);
            }

        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Or if you're not using Java 7, you'll have to do it the old school way and use `try-catch-finally`

```
Statement sta = null;
try {
    sta = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = sta.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //...
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (sta != null) {
            sta.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

In either case, it's guaranteed, that no matter what happens (short of the JVM dying mid execution), an attempt is made to close the resources.

Comment: You can actually define multiple resources in a single `try (....)`. It reduces the nesting

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, I'm kind of old school that way :P

Comment: BTW: Another case: reusing the statement `sta` by executing another query on it will close the `ResultSet` from an earlier execute on the same statement object.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I gotta stop look at that code...keep finding issues :P

Answer (score -3):

```
Dataconnection dbconnect = new Dataconnection();
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con = dbconnect.getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement("query");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) 
    {

    }

} catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally 
{
    try {
        if (rs != null) 
        {
            rs.close();
            rs = null;
        }
        if (ps != null) 
        {
            ps.close();
            ps = null;
        }
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.close();
            con = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ee)
    {
        System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to what is wrong with the code in the question, and how your code addresses these problems. Just dumping code without explanation is usually not very helpful (not for the asker, nor for future visitors).

Comment: what i want to do is to update an Access Database using Java and this is what i write to do this>> can anyone suggest another way to update an access database using java ??

Comment: Maybe use more try-with-resources and real error handling rather than just dumping the stack trace to stdout.